# Character in Huffman encoding

Tags: data-compression

Is a full stop regarded as a character along or must it be with a space in huffman encoding. I know of taking a comma with a space to a character.

Comment: Nobody or almost nobody here is reading the same textbook that you are reading, or taking the exact same course that you are taken. You need to give context in your question to be understood. We can use Huffman coding as a part of the process of encoding video. Where do you find full stops and space characters when you encode video?

Answer (score 1):

Huffman coding works with any character set.